# UIImageView animationImages strange behavior

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I'm populating the animationImages field of my UIImageview via NSArray arrayWithObjects.  When I put objects in the array via UIImage imageNamed: the UIImageview animates as expected.  However when I put objects in the array via UIImage alloc initWithContentsOfFile I don't see the animated images (I just see the default image I pass to initWithImage for the UIImageview).  Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `imageNamed:` and `initWithContentsOfFile:` both look in different directories. `imageNamed:` looks in your bundle directory, `initWithContentsOfFile:` does not.

If you have code like this:

```
NSString *file = @"image.png";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:file];
```

But you want to use `initWithContentsOfFile:`, you should use this code:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  I am using initWithContentsOfFile correctly.  For example I can load images with this method and pass them to the UIImageview's initWithImage and the single image is displayed correctly.